# Boostrapvalidator not fired

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate my form, but however, the boostrap validator never call.
https://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/24hzp7mk/12/

```
        $('#form_hr').bootstrapValidator({
```

i don' t know where the problem is coming from, can you help me out

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gaganshera/24hzp7mk/13/

Your js link wasn't working. Corrected it to

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is fine - the problem is with how you reference the file ;)

If you look at your JSFiddle includes, you're loading Bootstrap Validator from:

`tps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js`.

You simply missed the starting `ht` :)

I've fixed this reference, and created a new working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/tttdn5w4/).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `bootstrapvalidator` **reference** link is broken, use the following:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js